# Not able to open the anaconda-navigator because of ERROR ads._log_errors:19 (Data is not fetched with status 522)

Tags: anaconda

2022-03-17 01:26:05,501 - ERROR ads._log_errors:19
Tried to load advertisement image from https://optimise2.assets-servd.host/voracious-blesbok/production/api/navigator/Navigator-Commercialv6.png?w=315&auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=crop&dm=1643727003&s=77c3c1e618c897e6f1b9081f29103c53. Data is not fetched with status 522

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I get the same issue. Anaconda won't start from the shortcut.  But if I run manually from the Anaconda Powershell:

anaconda-navigator.exe

Then it launches okay. The same error appears, but the Navigator does launch.

I'm not sure if this was required, but I also ran the following before launching:

```
conda update --prefix d:\path\to\your\anaconda3\ anaconda
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update --all
```